# Oracle Sql - Getting Query result is signifitletly slower today than yesterday

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables on the same schema in a Oracle database.

The first table has 7 million rows, and is not updated any more. (no inserts) 
The second table has around 5 million rows, and is updated from time to time.

The problem: 
Until yesterday 
`SELECT count(*) from first_table` and `SELECT count(*) from second_table` 
both returned the result in around 0.5 seconds.

Today: 
 
`SELECT count(*) from first_table` --> 0.5 seconds 
`SELECT count(*) from second_table` --> 18-20 seconds.

To my knowledge, tables where not changed (keys, indexes, etc...), 
only a INSERT was done on the second table. The insert was not large at all.

How can i bring the execution speed of
`SELECT count(*) from second_table` back down to the desired time?

UPDATE:

Tried this, and it didn't help:
`EXEC DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS('SCHEMA','TABLE_NAME');` 
`ANALYZE TABLE izvod_raif_new COMPUTE STATISTICS ;`

Comment: You can't generally make a count query go any faster.  But, you could setup a trigger which keeps track of the count in that table.

Comment: Have the statistics been gathered on that table following the insert? Is there a primary key on the table?

Comment: Please check the question update. I tried that, and no difference.

Comment: Try Explain Plan on both statements and see if there is a difference (in index usage for example)

Comment: I think, if rows nad deleted and inserted, then must help: "ALTER TABLE V_SCHEMA.TABLE_NAME SHRINK SPACE"

Comment: *"a INSERT was done on the second table. The insert was not large at all"* That could just be a coincidence but it's the place to start. Does `second_table` have a primary key? Does it have LOB columns? Or lots of very wide VARCHAR2 columns? Is there other DML besides inserts occurring? Beyond that, has anything else changed? At it's simplest has the database been shut down and re-started?

Comment: @RustamPulatov I agree that the table might be fragmented, on a slow storage or otherwise, but I would not run such operations without diagnosing the problem first.

Comment: Use `GATHER_TABLE_STATS('SCHEMA', 'TABLE_NAME', CASCADE=TRUE)' so that index statistics are also gathered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running *explain plan*, as suggested by Cyrus in the comments, and digging a little bit:

`EXPLAIN PLAN FOR SELECT count(*) FROM first_table`

`EXPLAIN PLAN FOR SELECT count(*) FROM second_table`

And then:

`SELECT * from plan_table`

Revealed that the table was doing a **full table scan** every time, despite having indexes set.
Checking the table column information revealed that the script that was performing the insert, also set the index field to `Nullable=True`, which consequently broke the whole thing.

Answer (score 1):

> > an INSERT was done on the second table. The insert was not large at all.

Your performance may have been benefiting from Oracle's result set cache feature.  Here is an example of how that works:

#### Make a big, fat table and gather stats on it.

```
drop table big_fat_table;

create table big_fat_table ( id number, info varchar2(2000) );

insert into big_fat_table  select rownum id, lpad('x',2000,'x') info from   dual  connect by rownum <= 1000000;

commit;

exec dbms_stats.gather_table_stats (user, 'BIG_FAT_TABLE');
```

#### Make sure result set caching is off and try to count the records in the table a few times (using autotrace to see consistent gets

```
alter session set result_cache_mode = MANUAL;    
select count(*) from big_fat_table;
```

> ```
> consistent gets   334509
> consistent gets   333665
> consistent gets   333665
> consistent gets   333665
> ```

#### Enable result set cache and repeat...

```
alter session set result_cache_mode = FORCE;

select count(*) from big_fat_table;
```

> ```
> consistent gets   333674
> consistent gets   0
> consistent gets   0
> ```

#### Keeping the result cache enabled, add a small insert and repeat.

```
insert into big_fat_table values (1000001, 'more data');

select count(*) from big_fat_table;
```

> ```
> consistent gets   333666
> ```

I write this because it is consistent with your story, but a few things don't add up.  First, if you were really benefiting before from the result cache, your results prior to yesterday would have been better than 0.5 seconds.  Seconds, if it was really just the insert that threw it off, it should have gone back to normal on its own eventually.

But, there is no need to guess.  Run these queries in your database:

```
select * from v$result_cache_objects where name like '%FIRST_TABLE';
select * from v$result_cache_objects where name like '%SECOND_TABLE';
```

If you see results from the first one (which is still fast), but not the second one (which is slow now), then there is a good chance that the result cache is the reason for the performance differences you are seeing.